# CheckBox/RadioButton Required Validation JQuery MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

So I have this Model:

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool GreenCircle { get; set; }
    public bool BlueSquare { get; set; }
    public bool BlackDiamond { get; set; }
    public bool TerrainPark { get; set; }
```

Currently the View I have that allows a user to create a profile sets up Checkboxes for the bool properties listed here.

I am looking for a way to set up JQuery Validation that will require that one and only one of these bool properties is set to true so I'm thinking I should be using RadioButtons but I'm not quite sure how I can group those when they get set up in a View or how I can perform that type of validation.

Any ideas?  I'm here to learn so please point me in the right direction for research if you must; thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like an enum will more suit your needs.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an enum. For example:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    GreenCircle,
    BlueSquare,
    BlackDiamond,
    TerrainPark
}
```

Then use it in your model instead of four different boolean properties.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyEnum MyOption { get; set; }
}
```

Then generate radiobuttons in your view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MyOption, (int)MyEnum.BlackDiamond);
    <span>Black Diamond</span><br />
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MyOption, (int)MyEnum.BlueSquare, 
        new { @checked = "true" });
    <span>Blue Square</span><br />
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MyOption, (int)MyEnum.GreenCircle);
    <span>Green Circle</span><br />
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MyOption, (int)MyEnum.TerrainPark);
    <span>Terrain Park</span><br />
}
```

**Remark**: Maybe you can implement an HTML helper to generate the radio button markup for you.

Comment: Awesomeness.  I'm going to go give this a go, expect an update and thank you very much!

Comment: So despite the fact that my view is using a strongly typed model with the correct model referenced at the top I keep getting the error that: "ExperienceLevel does not exist in the current context" 

'public enum ExperienceLevel {......}
(in the model)public ExperienceLevel ExpLevel{get;set;}
(in the view)@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.ExpLevel, (int)ExperienceLevel.GreenCircle);'
It gives me the error on ExperienceLevel.GreenCircle

Comment: Scratch that, found a solution.  Thanks a bunch, it worked out perfectly.  I've got my list of RadioButtons.  Now I just need to work out how to get the value of the chosen RadioButton in my controller to work with it